# grab img src value using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to grab value of `img src` using following `HtmlAgilityPack` but this returns error that object is not found. Whats wrong i am doing here?

c#:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

string imgvalue = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@clsss='a-column a-span3 a-spacing-micro imageThumb thumb']/img").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Html:

```
<div class="a-column a-span3 a-spacing-micro imageThumb thumb">
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RHFEpd-nS._AC_SX60_CR,0,0,60,60_.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change clsss to class and try again. It should [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F240m.jpg)

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

string imgvalue = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='a-column a-span3 a-spacing-micro imageThumb thumb']/img").Attributes["src"].Value;
```